# Can't Replace TEMP labels in Chemnum

Tags: chemnum

When using [this .eps](http://sendspace.com/file/vvshv7) file exported from chemdraw (Mac OSX) I am unable to compile a scheme in TeXShop where the labels are replaced.

**EDIT1:** Upon adding the use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` as well as enabling shell escape in the engine, my compiler hangs and crashes.

EDIT2: I suspect I am not enabling shell escape correctly. By restoring the input latex parameter in engine to default followed by compiling the text I get:

> You need to run LaTeX with the equivalent of "pdflatex -shell-escape"

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{color}



 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,}

\author{\small{X and Y}}
\date{\small{30\textsuperscript{th} May, 2018}}
\title{ABC}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
     \begin{abstract}
xyz
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{Results and Discussion}


\begin{scheme}
\replacecmpd{first:compound}  
\replacecmpd{second:compound}
\replacecmpd{third:compound}
\replacecmpd{fourth:compound}  
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{untitled1}
\caption{This is something!}
\label{first:chem:scheme}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Comment: for some reason the download does not work here… The EPS *must* contain the strings `TMP1`, `TMP2` and so on as *text strings*. You can check if this is the case by opening the EPS with your editor and then search for the strings. (Some versions of ChemDraw don't safe the text as text…)

Comment: @clemens how do I search for the strings? I've opened the file in chemdraw and can just see the structures. Please try download from: https://www.sendspace.com/file/vvshv7

Comment: @Hazinga: You can open the .eps file in a text editor of your choice and use its search function to find `TMP`.

Comment: You forgot `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` (and `shell-escape`), see the `chemnum` manual for examples.

Comment: @clemens I can see TMP in the text editor.

Comment: @Marijn I have enabled shell escape in the engine of TexShop and introduced the auto-pst-pdf package just after graphicx. My TexShop hangs after compiling and crashes.

Comment: @Hazinga your code works for me (compiled with pdflatex and shell-escape enabled): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AheHi.png

Comment: @clemens Could you do a step-by-step for me? This still isn't working. In the engine under Pdftex (Latex field) I have: pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape. Also, I am clicking on Typset with Latex. The compiler simply hangs and crashes for me.

Comment: does a log file get written when it "crashes" if so what is in it

Comment: unrelated but `\small` does not take an argument so `\small{X and Y}` should be `\small X and Y` or better `X and Y` (you shouldn't put formatting in `\author` the formatting should be on the definition of `\maketitle`

Comment: @Hazinga I just copied your code from the question into my editor and compiled. That's it...

Comment: You could try compiling from the terminal/commad line, you may be able to see more warnings/errors/status messages than in a GUI editor.